# Как сделать блокировку таблицы в MySQL

Tags: сессия, база-данных, процесс, sql, mysql

Таблица InnoDB. Нужно сделать блокировку, запрещающую чтение и запись таблицы другими процессами одной и той же сессии. При этом, процессы другой сессии должны читать и писать её беспрепятственно, так же как и текущий процесс этой сессии. Возможно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько я помню такое сделать нельзя. Таблица либо блокируется вообще, либо не блокируется вовсе.

```
LOCK TABLES `some_table` AS t READ, t WRITE;
```

Потом делается просто:

```
UNLOCK TABLES;
```